# How put two gallery in LC Lightbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am doing my gallery and when i do a second gallery when I click on an image they come together and it shows me the images of gallery 1, how do I solve it?

```
<div id="lcl_elems_wrapper" style="position:absolute; left: 400px; top:460px; width:400px; z-index:6;">
    <a href="https://i.ibb.co/Cmhc8wN/PREMADE-PREVIEW-1.png" title="PREVIEW 1" data-lcl-txt="image 1 description" data-lcl-author="Beners">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Cmhc8wN/PREMADE-PREVIEW-1.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://i.ibb.co/Cmhc8wN/PREMADE-PREVIEW-1.png" title="PREVIEW 2" data-lcl-txt="image 2 description" data-lcl-author="Beners">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Cmhc8wN/PREMADE-PREVIEW-1.png">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="lcl_elems_wrapper" style="position:absolute; left: 400px; top:1460px; width:400px; z-index:6;">
    <a href="https://i.ibb.co/txR1yvG/aaa.png" title="PREVIEW 1" data-lcl-txt="image 1 description" data-lcl-author="Beners">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/txR1yvG/aaa.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://i.ibb.co/txR1yvG/aaa.png" title="PREVIEW 2" data-lcl-txt="image 2 description" data-lcl-author="Beners">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/txR1yvG/aaa.png">
    </a>
</div>    
    
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $obj = lc_lightbox('#lcl_elems_wrapper a');
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is lc_lightbox?

Comment: is a jquery of gallery